# Desktops compatible with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, compatibility

I'm looking to purchase a high-powered desktop that's compatible with 16.04, but the ubuntu certified page only lists one desktop that's certified to work.

Do any of you have any suggestions for good desktops that I could use with 16.04? I recently converted for my laptop and it's been working really well so I want to try and transition my desktop over too!

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware recommendation is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a high-powered system that is guaranteed to work with Ubuntu (with full support too), I would suggest [System 76](https://system76.com/). I have a laptop from them that is very nice, and works very well with Ubuntu.